# python doesn't read data sent from arduino correctly

Tags: python, arduino, serial-port, pyserial, arduino-uno

i was working on a project that includes sending 4 characters from arduino to python so that the first variable in python reads the first sent character and the second variable reads the second character but when i print them on the screen it's not stable and out of sync.
i.e:
i send 'a','b','c','d',and i expect to receive the same in python : 'a','b','c','d'.
but what i receive might be like this : 'c','d','a','b' or 'b','c','d','a'.

Arduino
`

```
void setup()
{

Serial.begin(9600);


}

void loop() 
{


Serial.write('a');
Serial.write('b');
Serial.write('c');
Serial.write('d');


}
```

`

Python

    `ser = serial.Serial('COM4',9600,timeout=0)
    ser.close()
    ser.open()
    up = ser.read()
    right = ser.read() 
    left =ser.read()
    down = ser.read()`

Comment: why not just `print ser.read(4)` ... you should see them all coming through in order ...

Comment: why dont you send a string like "A:B:C:D\n" (with newline delimiter), use serial.readline() and then strip new line,split string, get a,b,c,d :) it's more secure to get them in order, and be sure you discard your serial buffer when your app starts

Comment: i tried print ser.read(4) ... but it's the same the values keep changing

Comment: Marko Mackic . i think that might work but sorry i don't know how to do that i  don't know python i was just trying to make a simple program and i don't understand why my code isn't working

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm guessing it is because there is no synchronization between the two. The ardi sits there and spits out a,b,c,d,a,b,c,d,a,b,c,d  etc. When the python code connects, there's nothing to make the ardi start at 'a', it just keeps doing with it's doing and the python code gets data starting with whatever the ardi is on at the time. Notice in your problem description how the characters are always in order, if you allow for a repeating cycle?

Try having the python code (when it starts) to send something to the ardi so that it restarts the sequence from the beginning.